# How can I pass a [T] array to a C function expecting UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, and I can convert back returned C array to a swift array?

Tags: swift, unsafe

How can I use an `array: [Float]` as an argument of a `C` function with prototype `float* process(float*, int length)`.

This function takes an array of length `length` and return a new array of the same length.

How can I convert the result back to a swift array `[Float]`?

Comment: Does the `process()`  function mutate the passed array? Where is the returned array allocated, and who is responsible for releasing that memory?

Comment: The function `process()` has prototype `float* process(float* array, int length)`. The output has same length. It is not guaranteed the two pointer should be identical.

Could you tell me why you downvoted the question so that I can improve it?

Comment: I did not vote on the question or on your answer.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding.

I can also add for any one curious of the usage that I apply signal processing algorithm to a time series. This is the reason of this back and forth from Swift and C. Some times the length is preserved, some time it is not and I retrieve via a mutated parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from a `var array: [Float]` you can convert it to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` which is the equivalent of `float*` directly in your function call:

```swift
var array: [Float] = [1, 2, 3]

process(&array, Int(array.count))
```

From an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` you can convert back to an array with the buffer mechanism:

```swift
var buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<midi_note_data_t>(start: ptr, count: array.count)
var newArray = [Float](buffer)
```

As said in comment by Martin R, `UnsafeMutablePointer(mutable: array)` is . a copy of a reference whose validity end with the scope of the initialiser of this type. Therefore, it may in practice become invalid at any time.
[See the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer) for more details.

Comment: `var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(mutating: array)` is *undefined behavior:* A temporary pointer is created to the mutable element storage, and that is only valid during the call of the initializer. – It is much simpler: `let result = process(&array, Int32(array.count))`